# how can i extract baseline hazards from a coxPHFitter function in Lifelines and the coefficients for my variates

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, lifelines

Below is the sample code I got from the documentation website. I want to access the baseline hazards and the coefficients of the variates.
'''

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
from lifelines.datasets import load_rossi

rossi_dataset = load_rossi()


#rossi_dataset.head()
cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(rossi_dataset, duration_col='week', event_col='arrest',)

cph.print_summary()
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the lifelines [docs](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#fitting-the-regression):

> To access the coefficients and the baseline hazard directly, you can use `params_` and `baseline_hazard_` respectively.

```py
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
from lifelines.datasets import load_rossi

rossi_dataset = load_rossi()


#rossi_dataset.head()
cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(rossi_dataset, duration_col='week', event_col='arrest',)

print(cph.params_)

print(cph.baseline_survival_)
```

Comment: thank you. I have another question though? how can I access a specific baseline hazard for a specific duration?

Comment: `baseline_survival_` returns a DataFrame with an index, so you access it using normal dataframe operators: `.loc[t]`